# Object doesn't support property or method "EditDocument"

Tags: javascript, webdav, activexobject

I am trying to running this below codes, hoewever it prompt me an error that saying : Object doesn't support property or method "EditDocument". Can anyone help me why this error occurs?

```
<object id="winFirefoxPlugin" type="application/x-sharepoint" width="0" height="0" style="visibility: hidden;">Test-2.docx</object><a onclick='javascript: editDocument();' href='#'>Word Doc</a>

<script>
    var fNewDoc = false;
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var fNewDoc = false;
        var EditDocumentButton = null;
        try {
            EditDocumentButton = new ActiveXObject('SharePoint.OpenDocuments.2');
            if (EditDocumentButton != null) {
                fNewDoc = true;
            }
        } catch (e) {
        }
    });

    var L_EditDocumentError_Text = "Editing not supported.";
    var L_EditDocumentRuntimeError_Text = "Sorry, couldn't open the document.";

    function editDocument() {
        if (fNewDoc) {
            if (!EditDocumentButton.EditDocument(strDocument)) {
                alert(L_EditDocumentRuntimeError_Text);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                var hownowPlugin = document.getElementById("winFirefoxPlugin");
                hownowPlugin.EditDocument('http://localhost:46961/wordstorage/Test-2.docx', null);
            } catch (e) {
                alert(L_EditDocumentError_Text);
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

What is the browser that your are using to test this?

This should work in IE and FireFox browsers.

```
if (fNewDoc) {
    if (!EditDocumentButton.EditDocument(strDocument)) {
        alert(L_EditDocumentRuntimeError_Text);
    }
} else {
    try {
        var hownowPlugin = document.getElementById("winFirefoxPlugin");
        var version = hownowPlugin.GetOfficeVersion();
        hownowPlugin.EditDocument(strDocument, version);
    } catch (e) {
       // console.log(e);
        alert(L_EditDocumentError_Text);
    }
}
```